# SQL Query for emp and dept table in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

This is with reference to the emp and dept table of ORACLE. I want an output table to display dname, deptno, total salary for the employees hired in 1981 and 1982. I want the ouput in following fashion

Deptno | Dname | TotalSal_1981 | TotalSal_1982

I can find the total salary for employees  hired in 1981 in 1982 seperately. But how to club them to get output with above columns?

Thank you

Comment: can you give the table structure emp and dept

Comment: select deptno, dname, sum(salary)
from employees, departments
where employees.deptno = departments.deptno
and hiredate in (1981, 1982)
group by deptno, dname

Comment: EMP Table - empno(num), ename(varchar), job(varchar), hiredate(date), sal(num), deptno(num)                                                                                                         DEPT Table -- deptno(num), dname(varchar), loc(varchar)

Comment: @ thatjeffsmith your sql will give one clumn for total salaryof the employees hired in 1981-182. I want totl salry for the employeees hired in 1981 n 1982 in two different columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to join the employees hired in 1981 and 1982 and then sum conditionally:

```
select 
  d.deptno, 
  d.dname, 
  sum(case when extract(year from hiredate) = 1981 then sal end) as totalsal_1981,
  sum(case when extract(year from hiredate) = 1982 then sal end) as totalsal_1982
from dept d 
join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno and extract(year from e.hiredate) in (1981,1982)
group by d.deptno, d.dname;
```

Use a left outer join instead, if you want to show departments with no hired employees in these years, too.

Comment: There are several approaches to the task. This is just one of them. If you need alternatives, then tell me.

Comment: Hi Thorsten, Thank you very much. Now i want to be more specific on the query. If I want to find same information for a particular month of the year like Jan 1981 and Jan 1982 then what will be the syntax?                                                                                                       I also want to calculate the ratio of these two columns and show the display in another coumn 'Ratio'.

Comment: You get the month as you get the year: `and extract(month from e.hiredate) = 7`. You can also use TO_CHAR: `where to_char(hiredate, 'yyyymm') = '198107'`. As to the ratio: `select deptno, dname, totalsal_1981, totalsal_1982, totalsal_1981 / totalsal_1982 as ratio from (<above query>);`.

Comment: Hi, I am able to work with month. But getting p]error with ratio. as it is giving error saying totalsal_1981 does not exist.

Comment: The query in my answer contains a field totalsal_1981. You were to replace `<above query>` in my comment's query with the answer query. So there is a field totalsal_1981 to work with. Must be a copy and paste error or you renamed the field in the answer query.